# django: passing the form data from one view to another then commit save

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

i am a beginner and i don't know what i did wrong but here's what it should do

after filling up the fields in form and submitting it, the save_page will send a confirmation code in your email and you will be directed to another template where the valcode will ask for a code that save_page sent.

after submitting, the valcode will then check if your code matches the random generated code that save_page sent and if the code is valid then the data will be saved

here is my views.py

```
 if form.is_valid():  

        a = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12)))
        i = 1
        try:
            cde = APPLICANT_DATA.objects.get(code=a)
            i = 0
        except:
            i = 1

        while i ==  0 :

            a = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12)))
            try:
                cde = APPLICANT_DATA.objects.get(code=a)
                i = 0
            except:
                i = 1

        else:

            emails = form.cleaned_data['EMAIL']
            mail = EmailMessage('Your activation and application code is:  ' + str(a) +", do not show this to anyone", to=[emails])
            mail.send()
            cde = form.save(commit=False)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('verify')



else:
    form = application_form()

return render(request, 'frontend/apply.html', {'form': form})



def valcode(request):
sub_form = confirmform(request.POST)

if request.method == 'POST':

    if sub_form.is_valid():
        e = sub_form.cleaned_data['code']
        if e == a:
            cde.save()
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

thanks in advance

I have updated my code, i can't find a tutorial that answers my problem T.T and i also rephrased my question

Comment: You should be using the django models to interact with your database instead of opening a new database connection every time

Comment: i actually have a model, i did that because i have no idea how to check if it exists. . you can do validation in forms.py but how do i tell views.py that an error message has been raised?

Comment: You should spend some time doing the tutorials, and reproducing all steps. You may have the feeling that you loose some time, but looking at the code above, you will gain so much afterwards that you won't regret it.

Comment: also the validation/confirmation code that will be sent in the email is generated and stored in a variable("a") in save_page

Comment: yeah.. thanks but i am kind of rushing but i'll look in to it

Comment: It's hard for a beginner, any pointers? T.T